# How to skip pycaret data type validation step in docker

Tags: python, machine-learning, automl, pycaret

While we create a pycaret setup, e.g.:

```
from pycaret.regression import all

exp_reg101 = setup(data = data, target = 'Price', session_id=123,preprocess=False)
```

It will ask us to verify the data types like this; i.e:

```
Following data types have been inferred automatically, if they are correct press enter to continue or type 'quit' otherwise
```

I just want to skip this step and start the training process.

Because in local we can hit enter but while running it in docker it is not possibe to hit enter. so we will get EOF error while reading line error. or if there is any other way we can deal with.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `silent` parameter of `setup()`. [From the docs](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/classification.html#pycaret.classification.setup):

> **silent: bool, default = False**
>
> Controls the confirmation input of data types when `setup` is executed. When executing in completely automated mode or on a remote kernel, this must be True.